# Как пропорционально растянуть элементы списка по ширине?

Tags: css

Добрый день!

В резиновой вёрстке есть список из 6 элементов, расположенных в линию. Как сделать так, чтобы при растягивании элементы распределялись по ширине пропорционально? (Самый левый оставался всегда слева, самый правый в правой части, а те, что посередине, пропорционально растягивались). Есть идеи, как это сделать? 
Не все элементы имеют одинаковую ширину.

Comment: Таблицей пробовали?

Comment: или display: table-cell

Answer (score 1):

можно так:

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
        text-align: center;
}
li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скриптом.
Посчитать сумму ширин всех элементов, вычесть её из общей ширины, на которую они должны растянуться, поделить на количество интервалов между элементами, и задать левый маргин для всех элементов, кроме первого.

Примерно так:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$("li").each(function(){ totalWidth+=$(this).outerWidth() })
$("li+li").css({"martin-left": ($("ul").width()-totalWidth)/($("li").size()-1)})
```

Answer (score 0):

А можно сделать таблицей.

Comment: или для li убрать float и указать display: table-cell